# How to get Twilio for Salesforce Apex API intellisense in VSCode

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, vs-code, twilio

I have this Twilio package installed (in both environments):

- Twilio for Salesforce: [Production](https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t1N0000029Jrh) / [Sandbox](https://test.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t1N0000029Jrh)

I am using VSCode to build against the [Apex Query Library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/salesforce/using-twilio-rest-apis-apex):

**Example Apex**

```
TwilioSF.TwilioApiClient api = new TwilioSF.TwilioApiClient();
api.addUrlPart('Accounts');
api.addUrlPart('ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
api.addUrlPart('Messages.json');

api.addParam('To','+15558675310');
api.addParam('From','+15017122661');
api.addParam('Body','Here is my message');
TwilioSF.TwilioApiClientResponse response = api.doPost();

String sid = response.getTwilioJsonParser().get('sid').getString();
Integer totalSegments = response.getTwilioJsonParser().get('num_segments').getInteger();
```

**No API Documentation**

Unfortunately, Twilio don't seem to have API documentation which lists all the classes and their methods with usages.

For example, I want to know what methods the `TwilioApiClient` and `TwilioApiClientResponse` classes have.

**Question**

How do I make VSCode download the Twilio classes, so there is intellisense?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Whist it doesn't solve your issue, I recommend trying to open those classes in the Developer Console. Their accessible methods show all as global without meaningful code between, all returning null, but at least you can check its signatures and names, which helps.